# can't access ROS svn

Tags: ros, opencv, svn

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/trunk, but it's not accepting my username and password. I registered almost a week ago. I know it says there's a small delay between registration and being able to access the repository, but what it seems like it should be going through at this point.

Please help, I'm really stuck without being able to build OpenCV as armv6,armv7,universal

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31049/can%27t-access-ros-svn/) by [machty](https://answers.ros.org/users/2109/machty/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-04-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your url doesn't point to an existing project.  OpenCV is hosted at a different url: http://code.opencv.org/svn/opencv/trunk according to the OpenCV wiki: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OpenCV migrated to git. Please see http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki

---

Originally posted by [Giovanni Saponaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/595/giovanni-saponaro/) with karma: 68 on 2012-09-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1